# работа с файлом в с++

Tags: c++

Я делаю курсач, суть задания создания сделать телефонный справочник. Суть проблемы: я хочу сделать что бы ФИО адрес и номер телефона находился в файле.
но я не могу сделать  так что бы в файле был поиск допустим только по номеру или только по адресу.
например в файле есть строка
Петров И.А ул. Центральная +74563643234
и допустим тут нужен поиск по номеру телефона. как мне это реализовать?
мне нужно только разобраться как читать с файла

Comment: 1. Перечитайте вашу формулировку и испарвте так что бы было понятно. 2. Хранить в файле  телефонный справочник это хорошая идея. Вам необходимо завести себе структурку и сложить ее в вектор. Далее пробегая по вектору вы сможете легко вычитывать нужный обект.

Answer (score -1):

Вот вам заготовка:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


class Row{
public:
    static const std::string DELIMITER;
    std::string name;
    std::string place;
    std::string phone;
    Row(const std::string& name, const std::string& place, const std::string& phone):
            name(name), place(place), phone(phone) {}

    Row(std::string src){
        this->name = src.substr(0, src.find(this->DELIMITER));
        src.erase(0, src.find(this->DELIMITER) + DELIMITER.length());
        this->place = src.substr(0, src.find(this->DELIMITER));
        src.erase(0, src.find(this->DELIMITER) + DELIMITER.length());
        this->phone = src;
    }

    std::string dump() const {
        std::stringstream buffer;
        buffer << this->name << this->DELIMITER << this->place << this->DELIMITER << this->phone;
        return buffer.str();
    }

    std::string __repr__() const {
        std::stringstream buffer;
        buffer <<  "Row(name=" << this->name << ",place=" << this->place << ",phone=" << this->phone << ")";
        return buffer.str();
    }
};


const std::string Row::DELIMITER = "|";


int main() {
    std::vector<Row> phonebook;
    std::string opt;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Input opt: "; std::cin >> opt;
        if (opt == "read") {
            phonebook.clear();
            std::string filename;
            std::cout << "    Input filename: "; std::cin >> filename;
            std::ifstream in_f(filename);
            if (in_f.is_open()) {
                std::string line;
                while (std::getline(in_f, line)) {
                    phonebook.push_back(Row(line));
                }
                in_f.close();
            } else {
                std::cerr << "        File is not open:" << filename << std::endl;
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (opt == "add") {
            std::string name;
            std::string place;
            std::string phone;
            std::cout << "    Input name: "; std::cin >> name;
            std::cout << "    Input place: "; std::cin >> place;
            std::cout << "    Input phone: "; std::cin >> phone;
            phonebook.push_back(Row(name, place, phone));
            continue;
        }
        if (opt == "find") {
            std::string field, value;
            std::cout << "    Input field: "; std::cin >> field;
            std::cout << "    Input value: "; std::cin >> value;
            for (const Row& row: phonebook) {
                if ((field == "name") && (row.name == value)) {
                    std::cout << "        " << row.__repr__() << std::endl;
                }
                if ((field == "place") && (row.place == value)) {
                    std::cout << "        " << row.__repr__() << std::endl;
                }
                if ((field == "phone") && (row.phone == value)) {
                    std::cout << "        " << row.__repr__() << std::endl;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (opt == "print") {
            for (const Row& row: phonebook) {
                std::cout << "    " << row.__repr__() << std::endl;
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (opt == "write") {
            std::string filename;
            std::cout << "    Input filename: "; std::cin >> filename;
            std::ofstream out_f(filename, std::ios_base::out);
            for (const Row& row: phonebook) {
                out_f << row.dump() << "\n";
            }
            out_f.close();
            continue;
        }
        if (opt == "break") {
            break;
        }
        std::cerr << "Opt is error:" << opt << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: За что минус? Критика где?

Comment: Минус ставил не я, так что точно сказать не могу, но думаю, проблема в том, что в вашем ответе довольно мало пользы: какой-то код, который что-то делает. Как он работает. Зачем. Написать за человека курсовую не лучшая помощь в решение проблемы.

Comment: Ну автор же не поставил метку алгоритм, следовательно ожидал решения в коде.  А код довольно простой, не ясно откуда может быть проблема в понимании. + если автор спросит за что-то то я ему разьясню. Я ж не просто кинул простыню кода и ушел. Я здесь, и готов сделать консультацию)

Comment: Как раз в этом и проблема. Не хочется, чтобы сюда приходила куча студентов/школьников и постили сюда свои домашки/курсовые/дипломы получая на них готовый ответ. Всё-таки это не сообщество бесплатных фрилансеров, а нечто другое.

Comment: Ну так может имеет смысл обьявить тревогу или поставить минус вопросу, а не ответу?